# Can i define JSP Custom Error Pages for any of HTTP Client Error Code(4XX) and HTTP Server Error Code(5XX)?

Tags: java, jsp, custom-error-pages

I am using Jboss server, i want to know does it recognize all the HTTP Client Error Code(4XX) and HTTP Server Error Code(5XX) so that i can configure my custom error page like for 502, 503 etc. in web.xml? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: i did't find any documentation that has defined this. but @Jeremy suggested me a way to test it out: 
   Write a Servlet to return error code you want as following.

```
response.sendError([Error code goes here],
  "Error Message");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

To test this, write a servlet that specifically returns the error code.

Comment: thanks, But what i want to know is does it support another 4xx and 5xx error code, like 502, 503, 400 etc.?

Comment: @didxga - Why not? Write a servlet that returns the error code you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

There are few approaches to set custom error pages.

1. If you are using JSP's in presentation layer.

   foo.jsp

   ```
   <%@ page errorPage="/errorPage.jsp" %> // Here we are redirecting to error.jsp if any exception is thrown
   ```

   errorPage.jsp

   ```
   <%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
   ```

   I suggest this for development purposes.
2. At Application Level

   Setting errorpages in web.xml

   like above answer

   ```
   <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
   </error-page>
   ```
3. I still need to experiment with Container level, by editing web.xml found in jboss-web.sar or jboss-tomcatxx.sar